# iPhone:About UIPopoverController autosize self

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a Button in the ScrollView,and it will popup a UIPopoverController when user touches the button.

My propblem is: When I scroll the button up and I touch it,the Popover window will auto shrink itself.SO is there anyway to fix the Popover's size or to listen the shrinking behavior?

THanks in advance!

Comment: can you show the code on button click?

Answer (score 0):

Dont keep the popover arrow direction to top. keep it  `UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny` which will allow popover to display on bottom side of button , when there is no space at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by changing the popovercontroller.presentPopoverFromRect.myRect;